# Label not displaying value

Tags: iphone, objective-c

In my iphone application I want to display one value in a label situated in another class.for that i created an object of the class and displayed the value.It is working fine for the first time.But when the value changes,It is not displaying.But at the same time I can Log the correct value there.Any one know why it is??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2742403/update-label-value-in-cocos2d maybe check this link. Post some code though.

Comment: In which method (viewdidload or viewwillappear) you set label's text at first time ?

Comment: I have one method to display the value of this label.Every time when I need to display the value,I am calling that method...It works fine for the first time,but not changing the value from second time onwards

Comment: Is it the same label?  (print out the object pointer address).  Are you exiting from your method to the run loop after you update the label value.  (iOS won't redraw 'till then.)

Answer (score 0):

Try to send `setNeedsDisplay` to the view hosting the label right after the change happened.

Answer (score 0):

Is your label big enough to show the value? Does not have clear color? Is the font big enough to be seen? Isn't it overlapped by another view?

Are you not calling textField.text on a nil object?

Comment: this same label is displaying value once..I checked this by giving color

Comment: Ok, can you change other label property when changing the text? Like giving it a random background color? Try to log NSLog(@"%@", textField.text) before you change the text and after you change it.

Comment: I tried to change the label color..But it is not changing from second time onwards..I dont know what is going on:(

Comment: Try the log before and after.